# Why TO_CHAR(interval, format) works differently for 'weeks' than days/months in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-14

I am trying to convert an interval value to a string value using `TO_CHAR()` function. But I noticed when I pass formatter for weeks, it always returns at least 01, whereas it works as expected for days and months. For example:

```
postgres=# select to_char('2023-07-02'::timestamp - '2023-07-02'::timestamp, 'DD') as period;
 period
--------
 00
(1 row)

postgres=# select to_char('2023-07-02'::timestamp - '2023-07-02'::timestamp, 'WW') as period;
 period
--------
 01
(1 row)

postgres=# select to_char('2023-07-02'::timestamp - '2023-07-02'::timestamp, 'MM') as period;
 period
--------
 00
(1 row)
```

I even tried passing an interval like this:

```
postgres=# select to_char(interval '0 days', 'WW') as period;
 period
--------
 01
(1 row)

postgres=# select to_char(interval '0 days', 'DD') as period;
 period
--------
 00
(1 row)

postgres=# select to_char(interval '0 days', 'MM') as period;
 period
--------
 00
(1 row)
```

Please help. Is there any other way to convert an interval to 'weeks' string reliably?

Answer (score 0):

Just do it like this

```
select lpad(
    (abs('2023-07-02'::timestamp::date - 
         '2023-07-02'::timestamp::date)/7)::varchar
    , 2, '0') 
as period;
```

considering that

```
timestamp – timestamp returns interval and 
date – date returns integer (days)
```

and taking into account that is not possible extract weeks from intervals, just from time stamps because extract week returns the number of the ISO 8601 week-numbering week of the year, as can be seen in the [official documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT)

Comment: The actual inputs are timestamps, that's why in my example I've explicitly casted `date` values to `timestamp` values.

If I don't find any better alternative, I might just have to first extract the date part from timestamp values and then use what you suggested.

Thanks.

Comment: 1) The `date` will automatically cast to `timestamp`: `select to_char('2023-07-02'::date, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'); 2023-07-02 00:00:00` 2) The question is dealing with an `interval` not a `timestamp`.

Comment: Modified according to your comments. @DGulshan